# .NET Core How use different Environment?

Tags: asp.net-core, json.net, .net-core

I manage to have different Environments in web application.
In development environment I need to work on different database connection.
I tried to manage on next way but unfortunately doesn't works.
appsettings.Development.json

```
  {
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=xxx.xx.xxx.xxx;Database=dbName;User Id=xxPassword=xxxxxxx;"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  }
}
```

appsettings.json

```
 {
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=xxx.xx.xxx.xxx;Database=dbName;User Id=xxPassword=xxxxxxx;"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
public IHostingEnvironment environment;

public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{

    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: false)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    Configuration = builder.Build();
}

public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    if (environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    }
    else if (environment.IsProduction())
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    }


    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    // Add application services.
    services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
    services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));
    services.AddTransient<DbInitializer>();


    services.AddMvc();
}
```

With my code I'm getting an error when I start app.
**An error occurred while starting the application.**

General idea is when I'm in development environment to use appsettings.Development.json

Comment: Check this out for .NET 6: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76909010/8644294

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is code which is solving my problem.

```
private IHostingEnvironment _env;

        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            _env = env;


            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();

        }
```

Comment: Its looks like you just set $"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json" as optional and now you don't have an exception. Is you connection string set to correct server?

Comment: After deep investigation main problem was, in public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) there was written enviroment.IsDevelopment() that was always null. Than in Startup I made one instance of IHostingEnviroment which I can use in other parts of code, that instance get exactly enviromentname from Environment variables and check in ConfiguringServices and run correct connection string.

Answer (score 2):

you need to set your variabele. And then you create aditional appsettings..json files.

So you probarly already have you appsetings.json
We generally create also a appsettings.test.json and a appsettings.prod.json.

With this code in in the startup class, in the constructor:

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, ILogger<Startup> logger)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        Configuration = builder.Build();

        _logger = logger;

        _logger.LogInformation($"Env: {env.EnvironmentName}");
    }
```

you see this line: `.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", true)`

this one will overwrite the existing settings.
For example; if you host your app in azure, you need to set an application-setting with `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` with `test` or `prod`..

or offcourse you can set it on the property tab of your project

cheers!

Comment: for .net core 2.0 this has changed. Read https://joonasw.net/view/aspnet-core-2-configuration-changes for detailed answers.

Comment: Thanks for this - was driving me mad:         public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseEnvironment("Development")
                .UseStartup<Startup>();

Answer (score 1):

It's looks that you do not set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable to Development and uses  config file $"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json" as required (optional: false)

If you run application from command line you need to set up this variable.

For CMD:

```
set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
```

For powershell:

```
$Env:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = "Development"
```

If you are running project from Visual Studio, you can set this variable on "Debug" tab of project properties. You just need to add this environment variable using UI.

Answer (score 0):

For as far as I know the EnvironmentName is being set in the project's "Environment variables".

- Right-click on the project.
- Properties.
- Go to the Debug tab.
- Change the value of "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" to "Development".

Rebuild and `appsettings.Development.json` should be used.

[image: Environment variables]

Or on Azure:

- Go to your app
- click "Application settings"
- Under the title "App settings" you can add "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT"