# Use different appsettings.json on different machines having same environment

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-6.0, appsettings

I have a .NET 6 console app that runs on multiple servers to monitor apps on them.

The multiple servers already have their environment variable setup for other apps that use these values.

For example:

```
Server A -> DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT = dev
Server B -> DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT = qa
Server C -> DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT = prod
Server D -> DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT = prod
```

[image]

Even though both servers C and D are **prod** servers, they need different `appsettings` because they monitor different apps in those servers. So, having one `appsettings.prod.json` to be used in servers C and D won't work in this case.

I don't want to mess with the value of `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT` either because other apps running on that server are using it.

**What I've done so far**

I named `appsettings.json` files of my console app based on the server's name.

For example:

[image]

Added `launchsettings` profile to pass machine name as environment variable (for my testing):

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "AppStatusWatchDog (ServerA)": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "MachineName": "ServerA"
      },
      "dotnetRunMessages": "true"
    }
  }
}
```

And tried to load correct `appsettings.json` during startup:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var pathToExe = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;
    var pathToContentRoot = Path.GetDirectoryName(pathToExe);

    // Just calling Environment.MachineName is adequate here. GetEnvironmentVariable("MachineName") is here because we supply MachineName's value during local testing using launch profile.
    var machineName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MachineName") ?? Environment.MachineName;
    
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(pathToContentRoot)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{machineName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .Build();

    // Rest of the code here...
}
```

Here `config` loads all the settings I have, i.e. `appsettings.json`, `appsettings.ServerA.json` and the environment variables which is good .

The issue comes up  when I try to use config by injecting `IConfiguration` into a constructor of some class at which point, it loads `appsettings.json` and the environment variables but never the `appsettings.ServerA.json`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is that `pathToContentRoot` might not be correct when running in local debug or maybe the json file is not copied from project root to the build output directory... I'd check what `pathToContentRoot` is and verify that the files are present there. If they are - set `optional` to false and see what error you get.

Comment: Do you set a breakepoint at `var machineName` ? Can you get the machinename ServerA?

Comment: Figured this out and added my answer below. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `appsettings.X.json` config file is loaded into `IConfiguration` based on the value of `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT` variable for console apps. (`ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` for web apps. More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-7.0&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-2.0#environments)).

Try this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var machineName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MachineName") ?? Environment.MachineName;
    
    // IMPORTANT part: 
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT", machineName); 
    // For machine level change (Don't do this here):
    // Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT", machineName, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine); // Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19705691/8644294

    // If you're going to use config through dependency injection, you don't even
    // need to build 'config' below and this line CAN BE REMOVED altogether.
    // (Example of using config using dependency injection is shown below).
    // But for whatever reason you need 'config' in your 'Rest of the code here...'
    // part, keep this as is:
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        //.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()) // Not really needed though. Uncomment it if you'd like.
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{machineName}.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .Build();

    // Rest of the code here...
}
```

Use it like this:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;
    
    public SomeClass(IConfiguration config)
    {
        _config = config; //  This will have settings from appsettings.json, appsettings.ServerA.json, environment variables of the machine it's running on and so on.
    }
}
```

**Note:** Properties of your `appsettings.json` should look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you should modify your launch settings as follows:

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "AppStatusWatchDog (ServerA)": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "commandLineArgs": "--MachineName=ServerA",
      "dotnetRunMessages": "true"
    }
  }
}
```

Next, you need to modify your Main method to correctly parse the command line arguments:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var pathToExe = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;
    var pathToContentRoot = Path.GetDirectoryName(pathToExe);

    // Parse command line arguments to find the machine name
    var machineName = "default"; // Default value if no argument is provided
    for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
    {
        if (args[i] == "--MachineName" && i + 1 < args.Length)
        {
            machineName = args[i + 1];
            break;
        }
    }

    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(pathToContentRoot)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{machineName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .Build();

    // Rest of the code here...
}
```

let me know if it's resolutive for your problem.

Comment: Sorry, that didn't solve my problem. Thank you for your answer though. I just wrote my answer that worked. Check it out if you'd like.